# How to implement the two member functions (push_front and the destructor)?

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement two member functions, i.e., `push_front` and the `destructor`. I have written the code of the `push_front` function. But I seem, I am doing wrong anywhere. How can I fix this issue? How can I insert a node in front of `Linked-List` properly?

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
public:
    Node():next_p_{nullptr} {}
    Node(T v, Node* n):data_{v}, next_p_{n} {}
   ~Node() {};

    void     setData( T &v ) { data_ = v; }
    const T &getData() const { return data_; }
    void  setNext( Node *n ) { next_p_ = n; }
    Node *getNext() const { return next_p_; }

private:
  T data_;
  Node *next_p_;
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
private:
  Node<T> *head_ptr_;
public:
    LinkedList():head_ptr_{nullptr} {}
   ~LinkedList() {
    }

    // Insert at the front of the linked list (UPDATED)
    void push_front( T v ){
        Node *new_node = new Node;
        new_node->setNext(*head_ptr_) = v;
        new_node->next_p_ = this->head_ptr_;
        this->head_ptr_ = new_node;
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't insert numbers, you insert nodes. Since `Node` is a template class, it can contain any type of data.

Comment: You create a new `Node`, set its`next` pointer to point to the old `head_ptr`, then set `head_ptr` to point to the new `Node`.

Comment: Single linked list push_front involves creating a new node, setting it's next pointer to the current list head pointer, then setting the lists head pointer to the new node just-allocated. Destroying the linked list is simply an enumeration of all the nodes, destroying them as you go along. And with that, you'd better read [What is the Rule Of Three?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). It is highly relevant to your code.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for your comment. Please post it in details as an answer for better understanding.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks for your comment. Please post it in details as an answer for better understanding.

Comment: It wasn't an answer, it was just hints to help you get started.

Comment: @Barmar. Dear Sir, please explain it in detail. Because I am confused, how can I go ahead?

Comment: I don't know how to explain in more detail without doing your homework for you by writing the code. There isn't really much more to it than I said before.

Comment: @Barmar, Dear Sir, Please have a look at the `push_front` function. If I do anything wrong please let me correct it. PLEASE, SIR.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Dear Sir, Please have a look at the `push_front` function. If you have any correction please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `Node` constructor takes the value and next pointer, use that to create the new node in one step.

You shouldn't dereference `head_ptr_` when using it as the next pointer. It's already a `Node*`, which is the correct type for `head_ptr_`.

```
    void push_front( T v ){
        Node *new_node = new Node(v, head_ptr_);
        this->head_ptr_ = new_node;
    }
```

Comment: Or, if feeling particularly brief, `head_ptr_ = new Node(v, head_ptr_);`

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend not dealing with manual memory management and instead use smart pointers to simplify your life a bit.

Using `std::unique_ptr` you wont have to deal with reclaiming the memory you allocated from the free store.

One caveat to this approach is you lose your ability to copy the `List` but usually that's what you want anyway.

```
template<typename T>
class List { 
    struct Node { 
        Node( T value ) noexcept
            : data{ std::move_if_noexcept( value ) }
        { }

        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next{ nullptr };
    };
public:
    auto push_front( T value ) -> void {
        auto node{ std::make_unique<Node>( std::move_if_noexcept( value ) ) };
        std::swap( node->next, head_ );
        std::swap( head_, node );
    }

    ~List()
    {
        while (head_) {
            std::unique_ptr<Node> tmp(std::move(head_));
            head_ = std::move(tmp->next);
        }
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head_{ nullptr };
};
```

Comment: Be careful when doing this. It is trivial to create a linked list with thousands (or many more) nodes that results in a recursive delete operation as deep as the list is long whence the list is destroyed. It can (and will, if allowed) obliterate the activation stack of your thread, and then you're sad, as your program will literally "go off the deep end". A user-defined destructor equipped with a crafty set of move operations against the head pointer and a very-local temporary unique pointer can rectify that scenario (and yes, there are other ways as well).

Comment: @WhozCraig is this because of the reference to self in `Node`?

Comment: Its because an instance isn't finished being destroyed until its members are. Then the whole show moves to the bases, but that's not really relevant here. Picture the node pointed to by the head pointer. To destroy that instance, it's members (specifically, its next pointer) must be destroyed as well. Rinse, repeat, recursing each time until we hit end-of-list, which has an unbound next.  You've recursed N-1 times for an N-length list, If you managed to survive that without blowing out your call-stack the whole thing unwinds, finishing instance destruction at each step on the way out.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah I understand now. That also clarifies a question someone had at one of Herbs talks on `atomic`'s where he used `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>` to avoid the `ABA` problem for his `LinkedList` implementation.

Comment: I'll add an example of how to fix this in your code. Its a simple destructor. As I said, there are multiple ways to do this, but this is one of the more language-crafty methods.